# Logging out (or switching user) from spring security oauth2

Tags: logout, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I am having a problem with logout with spring security and oauth2.  I have a client gateway which houses the UI, an authorization server, and several resource servers.  The expected behavior is that when the user clicks on the logout link, they are just logged out from the client gateway and when the page reloads it should redirect back to the authorization server since the entire app is locked down.  If the user is logged out of the authorization server that is acceptable too.  The UI is in angular.  The logout function I am calling is

```
$scope.logout = function() {
          $http.post('/logout', {}).success(function() {
            $location.path("/");
          }).error(function(data) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          });
        }
```

When this is called, the resposne I get is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9999/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=ui&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login?logout&response_type=code&state=mj2HVD. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Obviously this is a cross site error which does not make any sense to me because the login portion works fine.

AuthServerApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class AuthServerApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthServerApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Autowired // <-- This is crucial otherwise Spring Boot creates its own
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        log.info("Defining inMemoryAuthentication (2 users)");
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()

                .withUser("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER")

                .and()

                .withUser("admin").password("password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()

                .and()

                .httpBasic().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${config.oauth2.privateKey}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
        log.info("Initializing JWT with public key:\n" + publicKey);
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the security constraints on the token endpoints /oauth/token_key and /oauth/check_token
     * Client credentials are required to access the endpoints
     *
     * @param oauthServer
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasRole('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')") // permitAll()
                .checkTokenAccess("hasRole('TRUSTED_CLIENT')"); // isAuthenticated()
    }

    /**
     * Defines the authorization and token endpoints and the token services
     *
     * @param endpoints
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints

                // Which authenticationManager should be used for the password grant
                // If not provided, ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter is not configured
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)

                        // Use JwtTokenStore and our jwtAccessTokenConverter
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer())
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()

                // Confidential client where client secret can be kept safe (e.g. server side)
                .withClient("confidential").secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/admin").autoApprove(true)

                .and()

                .withClient("ui").secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/").autoApprove(true)

                .and()

                        // Public client where client secret is vulnerable (e.g. mobile apps, browsers)
                .withClient("public") // No secret!
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "implicit")
                .scopes("read")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/").autoApprove(true)

                .and()

                        // Trusted client: similar to confidential client but also allowed to handle user password
                .withClient("trusted").secret("secret")
                .authorities("ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/").autoApprove(true)
        ;
    }

}
```

GatewayApplication

```
   @EnableZuulProxy
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableCircuitBreaker
    public class GatewayApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso 
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                 .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                 .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/beans", "/user").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterBefore(new RequestContextFilter(), HeaderWriterFilter.class)
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }

    }

}
```

It would also be acceptable if I could just switch the user.  If I missed any relevant code, you can look at the repo [here](https://github.com/tdelesio/leagues_ms).

Comment: how did u solve this problem ?

Comment: is possible to use switch user filter?